# PHP Password Generator Form within Form

Tags: php, html, forms

I have found a password generator and would like to have a form which allows a user to register but if they wish to generate a password they can press Generate password and it fills in a text input box with the password.

I then want them to be able to press Register and it sends all of the form data with either the manually set password or the generated password to the form submission.

Any ideas how I can put the form within a form with it being valid HTML?

My code is as follows:

```
<form id="register" action="registerprocess.php" method="post">
    <span><strong>Please note all fields are required</strong></span><br /><br />
    <label for="fullname">Full Name: </label><input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" required><br />
    <label for="email">Email Address: </label><input type="email" id="email" name="email" required><br /><br />
    <label for="manualpass">User-Defined Password: </label><input type="text" id="manualpass" name="manualpass" required><br />
    <?php

    $f_contents = file("..\sec\possiblewords.txt");
    $word = $f_contents[rand(0, count($f_contents) - 1)];

    function vowelreplacement() {   
        global $word;
        $string = $word;
        $trans = array("a" => "4", "e" => "3", "i" => "1", "o" => "0");

        return strtr($string, $trans);
    }           

    $generatedpassword = vowelreplacement();

    ?>
    <form id="vowelremover" method="post">          
        <label for="generatedpass">Generated Password: </label><input type="text" id="generatedpass" name="generatedpass" value=<?php echo $generatedpassword;?> required><input type="submit" value="Generate Password">
    </form>
    <input type="submit" value="register">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for your form in a form? It can probably be condensed into "just a form".

Comment: That has been done for you :)

Comment: this wouldn't be very secure, as you are exposing all your generated passwords quite easily!

Comment: This is still only dev phase so security and stuff I am looking to improve later but at the moment, please can we focus on the question in hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement jQuery Plugin and then do the following:

ajax.php (e.g. on server test.com)

```
<?php

$f_contents = file("..\sec\possiblewords.txt");
$word = $f_contents[rand(0, count($f_contents) - 1)];

function vowelreplacement() {   
    global $word;
    $string = $word;
    $trans = array("a" => "4", "e" => "3", "i" => "1", "o" => "0");

    return strtr($string, $trans);
}           

echo vowelreplacement();
```

form.php (php file where you place your form)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="register" action="registerprocess.php" method="post">
    <span><strong>Please note all fields are required</strong></span><br /><br />
    <label for="fullname">Full Name: </label><input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" required><br />
    <label for="email">Email Address: </label><input type="email" id="email" name="email" required><br /><br />
    <label for="manualpass">User-Defined Password: </label><input type="text" id="manualpass" name="manualpass" required><br />

    <form id="vowelremover" method="post">          
        <label for="generatedpass">Generated Password: </label><input type="text" id="generatedpass" name="generatedpass" value=<?php echo $generatedpassword;?> required><input type="submit" value="Generate Password">
    </form>
    <input type="submit" value="register">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

    $("#vowelremover").submit(function() {

        $("#generatedpass").load("http://test.com/ajax.php");

        return false;
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate your password with PHP you have to deal with [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) and then put the result of your Ajax response to your input using Javascript.

Either there are also many javascript passwords generators that can help you with this

Answer (score 0):

You can load the new generated password via AJAX into the password-field. The user can click a link next to the password-field to fill in the field with one of your generated passwords.

Another option would be to generate the password with javascript and put it into the field. Then you would not need the php-script to generate and the js would be simplified.

Answer (score -1):

The jquery plugin has many features that can simplify your tasks. see [HERE](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/forms/docs-forms.html) for the sample you are looking for (Refresh one element of a form)

Answer (score -4):

I have far much better and fully functional VB code for Random Password Generator.  This is my own program written in VB Express.  User have choice to select the length of the password and select from Upper, Lower, Number or Special Characters.  You can generate endless password from 8 to 25 characters.  Here is the code and .RAR file to download full program.  Best is... ITS FREE!!!

```
\\\======================================================================\\\
Option Explicit On
'---------------------------------------------------------------------
'---------------------------------------------------------------------
'---------------------- Password Generator ® -------------------------
'---------------------- Author: Chirag Patel -------------------------
'---------------------- Current Version: 1.x -------------------------
'---------------------- Date: August, 14, 2015 -----------------------
'---------------------- License: FREE License Program ----------------
'---------------------------------------------------------------------
'---------------------------------------------------------------------

Public Class frmPassGen
    'Declearing main intiger which will hold password
    Dim Letters As New List(Of Integer)

Public Function Info()
    'This button provide information about author 
    Dim Infor As String

    Infor = MsgBox("Program:  Password Generator ®" & _
                  vbCrLf & "---------------------------------" & _
                  vbCrLf & "Version: 1.0" & _
                  vbCrLf & "Programmer: Chirag Patel" & _
                  vbCrLf & " " & _
                  vbCrLf & "Legal Verbiage" & _
                  vbCrLf & "-----------------" & _
                  vbCrLf & "This program is FREE License program." & _
                  vbCrLf & " " & _
                  vbCrLf & "Thank you." & _
                  vbCrLf & "Chirag Patel", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Password Generator")
    cmbLength.Focus()
End Function

Public Function Clear()
    On Error Resume Next
    'Clears ALL
    cmbLength.Text = "000"
    cmbLength.Focus()
    txtPassword.Text = "... Your Password ..."
    chkUpper.Checked = False
    chkLower.Checked = False
    chkNumber.Checked = False
    chkSpecial.Checked = False
    txtLPass.Text = ""
    cmbNpass.Text = "000"
End Function

Public Function Upper()
    'Add ASCII Codes For Upper Case Letters
    For i As Integer = 65 To 90
        Letters.Add(i)
    Next
End Function

Public Function Lower()
    'Add ASCII Codes For Lower Case Letters
    For i As Integer = 97 To 122
        Letters.Add(i)
    Next
End Function

Public Function Numbers()
    'Add ASCII Codes For Numbers
    For i As Integer = 48 To 57
        Letters.Add(i)
    Next
End Function

Public Function Special()
    'Add ASCII Codes For Special Characters
    For i As Integer = 33 To 47
        Letters.Add(i)
    Next
End Function

Public Function uRemove()
    Dim rRnd As New Random
    Dim rSB As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    Dim trPass As Integer
    'Remove ASCII code for Upper case letters
    For i As Integer = 65 To 90
        Letters.Remove(i)
    Next
    'Remove ASCII Codes For Lower Case Letters
    For i As Integer = 97 To 122
        Letters.Remove(i)
    Next
    'Remove ASCII Codes For Numbers
    For i As Integer = 48 To 57
        Letters.Remove(i)
    Next
    'Remove ASCII Codes For Special Characters
    For i As Integer = 33 To 47
        Letters.Remove(i)
    Next
    'Remove cache
    For count As Integer = -1 To Val(cmbLength.Text)

        trPass = rRnd.Next(0, Letters.Count)
        rSB.Append(Chr(Letters(trPass)))

    Next
    txtPassword.Text = rSB.ToString
End Function

Private Sub cmdExit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdExit.Click
    On Error Resume Next
    'Exit Program
    Me.Close()
    End
End Sub

Private Sub txtPassword_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtPassword.KeyDown
    On Error Resume Next
    'Doesn't allow to change password
    txtPassword.Text = ""
    MsgBox("You cannot change password here.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Password Generator")
    txtPassword.Text = "... Your Password ..."
    cmbLength.Text = "000"
    cmbNpass.Text = "000"
    cmbLength.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub frmPassGen_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    On Error Resume Next
    'Default Settings
    cmbLength.Text = "000"
    cmbNpass.Text = "000"
    cmdOK.Enabled = False
    txtPassword.Text = "... Your Password ..."
    cmbLength.Focus()
    lbltTime.Text = TimeOfDay
    Me.Text = "Password Generator -  " & Format(Date.Now, "dddd, MM-dd-yyyy")
End Sub

Private Sub cmbLength_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbLength.SelectedIndexChanged
    On Error Resume Next
    'Enable Generate Button
    If cmbLength.Text = "000" Then
        cmdOK.Enabled = False
    Else
        cmdOK.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmdInfo_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdInfo.Click
    On Error Resume Next
    'Display Program Info
    Call Info()
End Sub
Private Sub cmdOK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdOK.Click
    On Error Resume Next
    For i As Integer = 0 To Val(cmbNpass.Text)              'Number of passwords need to generate

        'Disabled OK (Generate) Button when no options are selected
        If chkLower.Checked = False And chkNumber.Checked = False And chkSpecial.Checked = False And chkUpper.Checked = False Then
            MsgBox("Please select at list one of the four options to generate new random password.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "...Password Generator")
            cmbLength.Focus()
            cmdOK.Enabled = False
        End If

        'Decleration of Variables 
        Dim Rnd As New Random                           ' Generates Random Strings
        Dim SB As New System.Text.StringBuilder         ' Bings the String generated by Rnd
        Dim tPass As Integer                            ' Temp Variable to hold the generated string in temp continer

        'Condition...
        If cmbLength.Text = "000" And cmbNpass.Text = "000" Then
            Beep()
            MsgBox("You must select the length and numbers password.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Password Generator")
        Else
            cmdOK.Enabled = True
        End If
        'Creating password string...

        For count As Integer = 1 To Val(cmbLength.Text)     'Length of password

            tPass = Rnd.Next(0, Letters.Count)
            SB.Append(Chr(Letters(tPass)))
            Resume
        Next
        If Val(i) = 1 Then                                      'One Password Generated
            txtPassword.Text = SB.ToString
        Else
            txtPassword.Text = SB.ToString                     'More Password Generated
            txtLPass.Text += txtPassword.Text & vbNewLine
        End If
    Next


    'Disabled OK (Generate) Button when no options are selected
    If chkLower.Checked = False And chkNumber.Checked = False And chkSpecial.Checked = False And chkUpper.Checked = False Then
        cmbLength.Text = "000" And cmbNpass.Text = "000"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmbLength_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles cmbLength.KeyDown
    On Error Resume Next
    'Doesn't allow users to alter the value in selection (drop down box)
    cmbLength.Text = ""
    cmbLength.Text = "000"
    MsgBox("Sorry, you cannot alter the value in this area.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Password Generator")
End Sub

Private Sub chkUpper_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkUpper.CheckedChanged
    If chkUpper.Checked = True Then
        Call Upper()
    Else
        'Remove ASCII code for Upper case letters
        For i As Integer = 65 To 90
            Letters.Remove(i)
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub chkLower_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkLower.CheckedChanged
    If chkLower.Checked = True Then
        Call Lower()
    Else
        'Remove ASCII Codes For Lower Case Letters
        For i As Integer = 97 To 122
            Letters.Remove(i)
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub chkNumber_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkNumber.CheckedChanged
    If chkNumber.Checked = True Then
        Call Numbers()
    Else
        'Remove ASCII Codes For Numbers
        For i As Integer = 48 To 57
            Letters.Remove(i)
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub chkSpecial_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkSpecial.CheckedChanged
    On Error Resume Next
    'Checks if the Special Checkbox is checked
    If chkSpecial.Checked = True Then
        Call Special()
    Else
        'Remove ASCII Codes For Special Characters
        For i As Integer = 33 To 47
            Letters.Remove(i)
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmdClear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdClear.Click
    On Error Resume Next
    'Call Clear
    Call Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    lbltTime.Text = TimeOfDay
End Sub

Private Sub txtLPass_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtLPass.KeyDown
    On Error Resume Next
    'Doesn't allow Edit...
    MsgBox("You cannot alter the password here.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Password Generator")
    Call Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub cmbNpass_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbNpass.SelectedIndexChanged
    On Error Resume Next
    'Enable Generate Button
    If cmbNpass.Text = "000" Then
        cmdOK.Enabled = False
    Else
        cmdOK.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: "Far better solution" might be your opinion. But let's not be putting down on others' solutions. Also, you posted this to a question asked, and answered (with an *accepted* answer) 3 years ago. And... you don't need to talk about how your solution is FREE (and it's not a place to promote your software). Lastly: You have some formatting errors you might want to fix.